# How to set the cpu frequency to the max on SLES12?

Tags: cpu, sles

I tried:

```
cpupower frequency-set -g performance
```

But still, the frequency is only at 1200 MHz.

It only goes up if I put a load on the machine, but it should be running at always 100% cpu frequency.

Using SLES 12.2.

```
SERVER:~ # cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.121-92.80-default root=/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root splash=silent quiet showopts console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600 elevator=noop transparent_hugepage=never crashkernel=768M numa_balancing=disable intel_idle.max_cstate=1
SERVER:~ #
```

What am I missing?

If it is maybe some UEFI settings, is there any command, ex.: asu64 to update the UEFI setting without a reboot?

Machine is a "x3850 X6", CPU is: " Xeon(R) CPU E7-8880 v4 @ 2.20GHz".

**Update#1**: found something, maybe:

```
SERVER:~ # systemctl start cpupower
Failed to start cpupower.service: Unit cpupower.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
SERVER:~ # echo $?
5
SERVER:~ #
SERVER:~ # systemctl status cpupower
? cpupower.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
SERVER:~ #
```

Update for the update#1: I followed the https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7021316 but didn't helped.

**Update#2:** tried to set the freq but didn't helped.

```
SERVER:~ # lscpu | awk '/Model name:/{print $NF}'
2.20GHz
SERVER:~ # cpupower frequency-set -u 2.20GHz
...
SERVER:~ # cpupower frequency-set -u 2.2GHz
...
SERVER:~ # lscpu |egrep  "CPU MHz|CPU(s)" | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F "." '{print $1}'
1200
SERVER:~ #
```

Comment: your CPU is "intelligent" if it doesn't need to run at 2.2Ghz it won't, it saves power and lifetime of your CPU, let it do it's job, it will work at max frequency if possible thermally when needed. If you want to run your CPU at maximum capacity maximum speed you can simulate an heavy worload with `stress --cpu 44 -t 10s` It will make your CPU goes to maximum capacity on all it's core, if you measure the clock rate you will see it should be at maximum. (if no thermal throttle)

Comment: machine has to be high perf. freq should be max always :\

Comment: it is not a good idea to do so. This would reduce the life duration of your CPU your fans and probably will not help you that much being high perf at all. Do you have problem in perf with the current set up ? I never heard of problem with scaling CPU freq regarding perf it's much often a problem in software or IO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
cpupower idle-set -D 0
```

Comment: yapp, it worked, confirmed :) only issue it is not permanent, but a boot script can handle that